# How to assign content of a zip file to each task in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

So, I have an application where I have multiple zipped files located in an HDFS directory. I want to create an RDD, where each task works on the content of a zip file. At this moment, I create an RDD from files' names and within each task, read the content of a zip file, using the HDFS client library.

However, I don't want to do it like this, but instead have a task automatically assigned the content of the zip file. I think it would be more efficient this way, because the computational task would go to the node containing the zip file, while in my current approach, I bring the data to the computational task, which means the task may have to read a zip file distributed on some other node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Hadoop RDD API (sample PySpark code):

```
  newconf = {"mapred.input.dir": <<DIRECTORY>>}                        
    hadoopRdd01 = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat",
                                "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
                                "org.apache.hadoop.io.Text",
                                conf=newconf)
```

If you are using zip/ gz then the files are not splittable so each zip will be an input to a task & loaded to a partition.